# String equals to null even though it goes past the whileloop checking if its not equal to null

Tags: java

NO HELP RECIEVED..I FIXED IT MY SELF CANT REMOVE CODE. THANKS EVERYBODY WHO ACTUALLY HELPED NOT SPAM DOWN VOTES BECAUSE YOU DIDN'T LIKE THE QUESTION

```
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Login().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: You just dumped a whole lot of code there. Where's the actual code in question?

Comment: By any chance is the last line in the file "null"?

Comment: That's a lot of code and no info about where you see the `null` value. You should indicate where you get that value. Also, your code includes lots of rather useless `try-catch`-clauses. Either `catch` and handle the exception or catch it at a higher level where it can be handled.

Comment: And if you're talking about the commented code, the problem is that instead of using `a.split()`, you're telling the reader to read an additional line, which presumably doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi, my apologies. readFile and Writefile methods

Comment: The textfile created has the information arrayname and arraypass

Comment: So you guys just flagged down the question because you didnt like it

Comment: No.  It was down-voted because it is a poor Question.  Read the comments above again if you can't figure out why we think that.

Comment: continue downvoting guys..have all the fun you want

Comment: You were downvoted because you haven't read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Downvoting isn't fun.  It is, on the other hand, very useful for the community.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about these lines in readFile

```
    while((a=breader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.print(a);
```

then the only way that that `print` can output "null" is if you read the characters "n" "u" "l" "l" from the input stream.

Comment: the file has the information Moustafa:moustafa123 but reading this infomation.seems to be a dilemma for me

Comment: Well maybe it is outputting "null" in a different place. Or maybe you are reading a different file.  Or maybe it is not outputting "null" at all.

Comment: System.out.print(a) prints out null

Comment: The 'file' variable from readFile() doesn't have that information. You are creating that in writeFile().

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in readFile(), if the file doesn't exist, then you are creating a new file and then calling WriteFile();

The 'file' variable from readFile() is not the same as the one from WriteFile(). They are both losing scope out of the functions they are declared in.

Also, you might want to look into your naming conventions: usually class names are the ones starting with an uppercase letter. Functions and variables should start with a lower case letter. So WriteFile() should be changed to writeFile(), to be consistent with readFile().

Comment: Thank you. The only decent person on here who gave the appropriate help without needing to downvote in secret like the rest of them..stackover has started to go downhill with people coming to learn and having their questions flagged for whatever reason